# Как осуществить cron для экспорта данных с MySQL?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, cron

Есть таблица. Требуется выгружать данные таблицы в формате CSV в определенное время. Как это можно осуществить? Спасибо.

Comment: По тексту и в сабже просто SQL, но в тегах MySQL. Если верно второе - укажите везде MySQL, если у Вас другая СУБД - укажите именно её.

Comment: У Вас тут своя обстановка. Не вижу ссылку на редактирование поста.

Comment: Поправил. Спасибо.

Comment: Кстати, гугл по запросу "mysql to csv" дает хорошую подборку, остается положить в файл и его выполнение запланировать в cron. А что касалось вопроса про ftp есть отличный пакет ncftp для передачи файлов из скриптов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Требуется выгружать данные таблицы в формате CSV в определенное время. Как это можно осуществить?

```
CREATE EVENT export_to_csv
    ON SCHEDULE 
        EVERY 1 DAY
        STARTS CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
    DO
        SELECT * 
        INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/export.csv'
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
        FROM data_table;
```

Само собой event sheduler следует активировать. Подробнее [тут](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html).

Comment: стоит, вероятно, добавить, что полученный файл (после использования) надо удалить/переименовать. иначе (если файл имеется) mysqld не станет его перезаписывать: [file_name cannot be an existing file, which among other things prevents files such as /etc/passwd and database tables from being destroyed](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html#idm139694615881504)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin А вот этими вопросами теоретически должен заниматься уже CRON. Не дело серверу БД лезть в файловую систему... и наоборот.

Comment: **кто** должен заниматься — это понятно. но чтобы просто **начать** этим заниматься, администратор должен знать о такой особенности поведения *mysqld*. и о данной особенности, по-моему, стоит упомянуть в ответе (комментарии здесь, как вы знаете, неподходящее место для существенной информации)